# Which mock you use to test HttpClient?

Tags: java, junit, httpclient

I am writing my HttpLient based on RestTemplate.
Which mock you use to test HttpClient?

Answer (score -1):

Glad to answer this question.
Quick Guide to @RestClientTest in Spring Boot
https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot
Hope this is useful for you.

Comment: This would serve better as a comment than an answer. Either elaborate & summarise on the information provided in the link or convert this to a comment.